# Can I specify an Entity as a Datastore property to achieve join-like functionality?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datastore

For example, I have the entity Parent and the entity Child. Since the Datastore does not allow joins, I cannot specify parentKey as a property in Child. I mean, I can but that won't do me any good.

But if I want to retrieve Parent properties in queries to the Child, do I solve the problem by specifying the entire Parent entity as a property in Child? Is it proper to do so?

```
Entity parentEntity = new Entity("Parent");
// ... process parentEntity

Entity childEntity = new Entity("Child");
childEntity.setProperty("parentEntity", parentEntity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Entity` cannot be stored as a property within another model ([valid property types](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html#Properties_and_Value_Types)).

Instead, create one property on the child entity for each property you need a denormalized copy of in your child.

Comment: I see. This is still a bit of a brain-twist for me, but how do I ensure data remains normalized?

Comment: Do you mean how do make sure that the denormalized values in the client entity remain consistent with the values in the parent?  You just need to be sure you update your denomralized values whenever you change your `Parent` entities.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the datastore API doesn't support this, but G[uido's NDB project](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/) supports nested entities.